# Android: Drawing paths on a 3 dimensional cube

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app.

I want to be able to:

a) display a 3 dimensional object (like a simple cross section of a building)

b) draw lines on that object (like lines down the halls of that building)

I've tried LibGDX. I know there's a way to do this, but there's little resources on the internet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "there's little resources on the internet". I expect that its just you are trying to find one resource to solve your problem when you should break it up into smaller steps. You might want to show what you've tried to do a "cross section of a building". Regardless you should only have one question per post on StackOverflow.

Comment: good question now you need to find solution. you are on right track ...